# JSON.parse function in a for loop

Tags: javascript, json, function, for-loop

I have a problem with the JSON.parse function in a for loop. Standalone works the JSON.parse. In my Script in a for loop don't work it. It's a problem with a function in a loop? I have no idea.

My Idea: Parse a JSON via Overpass API in a loop for and generate a JSON as txt in the browser. (copy&paste it in a txt file and save it as *.js).

standalone:

```
function loadJSON(file, callback) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType('application/json');
    xobj.open('GET', file, true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == '200') {
            // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
            callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
    };
    xobj.send(null);
}

var lon = "9.841431";
var lat = "53.166591";

var overpassurl = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];is_in("' + lat + '","' + lon + '");out+body;%3E;out+skel;';

loadJSON(overpassurl, function (text) {

    var result = JSON.parse(text).elements[0].tags.name;

    document.getElementById("jsondiv").innerHTML = result;

});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5vqd7sm0/35/

My Script:

```
function loadJSON(file, callback) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType('application/json');
    xobj.open('GET', file, true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == '200') {
            // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
            callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
    };
    xobj.send(null);
}

var lonlatarray = [
    [9.841431, 53.166591],
    [13.544482, 52.509910],
    [13.218674, 52.428120]
];

var jsontxt = "var jsonobject = { ";
jsontxt += '<br>';

for (let i = 0; i < lonlatarray.length; i++) {

    var lon = lonlatarray[i][0];
    var lat = lonlatarray[i][1];

    jsontxt += '"' + i + '": {';
    jsontxt += '<br>';
    jsontxt += '"coords":["' + lat + '","' + lon + '"],';
    jsontxt += '<br>';

    var overpassurl = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];is_in("' + lat + '","' + lon + '");out+body;%3E;out+skel;';

    jsontxt += '"bundesland":"' + loadJSON(overpassurl, function (text) {
        return JSON.parse(text).elements[0].tags.name;

    }) + '",';


    jsontxt += '<br>';
    jsontxt += '},';
    jsontxt += '<br>';

}

jsontxt += '}';

document.getElementById("jsondiv").innerHTML = jsontxt;
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bk13f7qh/43/

Comment: If you are referring to the `undefined` value (as your problem) in the json then it is coming because of the `async` (loadJson) call. To resolve it either make the `loadJson()` as sync or get the data from the **Overpass API**  first then create the json file.

Comment: @vikschool: async: xobj.open('GET', file, false);

Comment: you can use the `sync` approach but as stated in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request) it is deprecated because of negative user experience.

Comment: "negative user experience" gnaaaaaaaaaaaaa... It works by me, waiting...

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `undefined` as the output from the `loadJson()` is not available at the time of execution as it is an [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function which is not going to block the further code from execution and as a result your code is going to the next request before getting the result from the previous request and as the previous request is not there yet it outputs as `undefined`.

As you have implemented here:

```
jsontxt += '"bundesland":"' + loadJSON(overpassurl, function(text) {
       return JSON.parse(text).elements[0].tags.name;
}) + '",';
```

And then you are trying to append the json text value to the `jsonDiv` from the `jsontxt` generated by your function.

So, as your main requirement is to get the data from the request in the loop then you have to change your implementation from what you have right now to this:

```
function exportJsonToFile(){

var jsontxt = document.getElementById("jsondiv"); //assigend jsontxt directrly to the control on which the data has to be assigned
var reqCount = 0; // a counter to be used for request context


function loadJSON(file, callback) {
  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.overrideMimeType('application/json');
  xobj.open('GET', file, false); 
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == '200') {
     // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
     callback(xobj.responseText);
     }
  };
  xobj.send(null);
}

var lonlatarray = [
 [9.841431, 53.166591],
 [13.544482, 52.509910],
 [13.218674, 52.428120]
 ];


jsontxt.innerHTML = "var jsonobject = { ";
jsontxt.innerHTML += '<br>';

for (let i = 0; i < lonlatarray.length; i++) {     
   var lon = lonlatarray[i][0];
   var lat = lonlatarray[i][1];

  jsontxt.innerHTML += '"' + i + '": {';
  jsontxt.innerHTML += '<br>';
  jsontxt.innerHTML += '"coords":["' + lat + '","' + lon + '"],';
  jsontxt.innerHTML += '<br>';



  var overpassurl = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];is_in("' + lat + '","' + lon + '");out+body;%3E;out+skel;';

  jsontxt.innerHTML += '"bundesland":"{' + i + '}",';

  loadJSON(overpassurl, function(text) {
   var name= JSON.parse(text).elements[0].tags.name;  
   jsontxt.innerHTML = jsontxt.innerHTML.replace('{'+reqCount+'}',name);
   reqCount++
  });

  jsontxt.innerHTML += '<br>';
  jsontxt.innerHTML += '},';
  jsontxt.innerHTML += '<br>';

}

 jsontxt.innerHTML += '}';
}
```

And then simply call the function `exportJsonToFile()`;

So, what I am doing in the above code is that when you loop through the location points I am appending a position of the data that is going to come in your `json Text` as {0},{1},{2} as written in here:

```
jsontxt.innerHTML += '"bundesland":"{' + i + '}",';
```

and then in the callback of the `loadJSON()` i am just replacing the above-assigned values with the actual ones and incrementing the `reqCount` variable as :

```
var name= JSON.parse(text).elements[0].tags.name;
jsontxt.innerHTML = jsontxt.innerHTML.replace('{'+reqCount+'}',name);
reqCount++
```

Comment: Thanks. That one solution. I found another over the hint from @vikschool by rewrite the loadJSON(). See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ct3pghvn/34/ But thats not my final solution. There is here: http://jsfiddle.net/bk13f7qh/120/